# Import in applications.yml not loading the file in spring.config.import

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a strange issue which has made me completely run out of ideas. I have a config class which fetches stuff like:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "n-config")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Config {
  ...
}
```

I have different settings.yml and different profile specific ones settings-{profile}.yml. These files are imported in the application.yml and the other profile specific ones, which is application-dev.yml and application-stage.yml.

The strange thing is the Config class is properly loaded in the stage profile and the application-stage.yml is something like this

```
spring:
  config:
    import: optional:classpath:conf/settings.yml, optional:classpath:conf/settings-staging.yml
```

This works and imports everything properly and my class has all the attributes from the settings.yml file.

Now application.yml is something like :

```
spring:
  application:
    name: Some app
  devtools:
    restart:
      enabled: false
  graphql:
    schema:
      ...
  datasource:
    ...
    hikari:
      ...
  jpa:
    ...
  config:
    import: classpath:conf/notification-settings.yml
```

This doesn't import the file and all the attributes inside the Config class but the stage ones work.

I have another for dev which looks like this

```
spring:
  config:
    import: classpath:conf/settings.yml, optional:classpath:conf/settings-dev.yml
  devtools:
    ...
  datasource:
    ...
    jpa:
      ...
```

and this doesn't load anything into the Config class. I have tried everything but I can't make any sense of it.
I have checked the path. I have switched names. I tried the path in local and put it in application-stage and that worked. Everything works in the stage one but not in application.yml and application-dev.yml